# How do I change this ggplot2 violin/box plot ordering

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

I have 4 columns: Genotype (CC or CT/TT) , and 3 columns of GDF levels at 3 time points GDFbase, GDFt6, GDFt12 (baseline, 6m and 12months respectfully)

I have basically created this violin / boxplot:
[image]
This is my code:

```
df <- GDF_for_R

df  %>% 
  drop_na(Genotype) %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("GDF")) %>%
  ggplot(. , aes(y = value, x = Genotype, group = Genotype, fill=Genotype)) + 
  facet_grid(~name)+ 
  geom_violin(width=0.5) +
  geom_boxplot(width=0.1, alpha=0.2)
```

But I need the the plots to be in the order of baseline, then t6 and then t12. How do I reorder them? Also, How do I rename them at the top to look nicer e.g. change "gdfbase" to "GDF baseline"?

Comment: You need to have `name` as a factor with the specified levels. Try adding the line `mutate(name = factor(name, c("GDFbase", "GDFt6", "GDFt12"))) %>%` after your `pivot_longer` line.

Comment: In regards to your second question, you could change the values in the relevant df column using `str_detect()` or similar  from the `stringr` package. It would go between `pivvot_longer()` and `ggplot(0`